# Auto installation of flash player

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flash, autorun

In my .NET based windows application I am using a flash component.

When installing my application on another system I want to automatically install flash player. Is this possible? How can I automatically install flash player with my application?

Comment: Is there really the need to use flash? Most things that can be done in Flash can be done in .net as well. Also, I think I once read bundling flash-player is in general considered bad practice and the most common workaround is to redirect people to the standard download page to download the latest version (or parse that in your installer). Don't think there's any "web install" setup available that will grab the latest version on its own.

Comment: @Mario: Some flash games are there. Also it is a stand alone application.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider adding the flash player to the setup as a requirement and it will all go smooth for the user.